# jsp version of an php program

Tags: php, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to develop a JSP program inspired from a PHP program but its not functioning the same way. What possible error can exist in this?

This is the PHP version

```
 <?php
  $hostname_localhost ="localhost";
  $database_localhost ="test";
  $username_localhost ="root";
  $password_localhost ="";
  $localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
   or
  trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query_search = "select * from salesperson where username = '".$username."'AND password = '".$password. "'";
 $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
  if($rows == 0)
 { 
    echo "No Such User Found"; 
     }
  else  {
   echo "User Found"; 
 }
?>
```

This is the JSP version

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
 <% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>

  <%
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");

  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

  Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;


  String resultset1 = "select * from test.salesperson WHERE username = '"+ username+"' AND password = '"+password+"' ;";
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(resultset1);
   if(resultset1.equals(null))
   {
    out.print("No Such User Found");
  }
  else
  {
    out.print("User Found");
   }
%>
```

This program has been written for an android login client but with JSP its not working.

Comment: What is it _supposed_ to do and what does it _actually_ do? [Please read this carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: does ResultSet class contains .equals method i am not sure cross check,use resultset1!=null or !resultset1.next()

Comment: @Bowdzone I am trying to do a function similar as mysql_num_rows for jsp. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(resultset1.equals(null))
  {
    out.print("No Such User Found");
  }
else
  {
    out.print("User Found");
  }
```

with

```
resultset1.next();
int rowCount = resultset1.getInt(1);
if(rowCount < 1)
{
    out.print("No Such User Found");

else
{
    out.print("User Found");
}
```

and see if it works.